# Increasing the volume of sound on Backtrack 4

Tags: linux, audio, livecd, backtrack

The sound on Backtrack 4 is too low, I am running a live CD but can't seem to find the volume knob.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `alsamixer` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Backtrack 5 R3 and may work on Backtrack 4.

Go to System » Preferences » Startup Applications

Make sure you’re in the tab ‘Startup programs’. Click on "Add". Then enter the following

- Name:    Pulseaudio daemon
- Command: `/usr/bin/pulseaudio`
- Comment: Start the sound daemon

Now logout, then login again. It's normal that sound doesn't work on Ubuntu 10.04 under root.